# pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

Tags: python, sql, azure

```
    def gotorasp1(self):
        with pyodbc.connect(
                'DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password) as coca:
            with coca.cursor() as cola:
                cola.execute("SELECT * FROM Data")
        mac = cola.fetchone()
        log = self.login.text()
        pas = self.passw.text()
        ind = 0
        check = 0
        while ind != 5:
            if log == mac.Login:
                if pas == mac.Password:
                    un = mac.Lname
                    check = check + 1
                mac = cola.fetchone()
                ind = ind + 1
        if check == 1:
            self.username_labl_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", un))
            self.login.setText("")
            self.passw.setText("")
            MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1180, 800))
            MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
            desktop = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop()
            x = (desktop.width() - MainWindow.width()) // 2
            y = (desktop.height() - MainWindow.height() - 90) // 2
            MainWindow.move(x, y)
            self.label_8.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"Montserrat\";\n""color:white")
            self.stackedWidget1.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2)
            self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", dw + "  " + today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")))
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[September] WHERE Day = {t}")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            ...
```

This error appears in this line:
`mac = cola.fetchone()`
And I,as a person who is not particularly versed in the topic, absolutely can not understand why.
I will be very grateful for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I like to just grab all the stuff at once and get it in a list. I also like to grab the column definitions as it is often needed.

```
column_definition = cola.description
rows = cola.fetchall()
```

Then loop on rows to do what you want, looks like your code loops on the first 4 rows to see if there is a single match. At any rate you will need to change that logic if this gets rid of the sequence error.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was that I stupidly broke the tab in one place,but thanks anyway!